# How to get the GLCM images to show in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, feature-extraction, glcm

I want to show the GLCMs of an image in Matlab. So far I've tried and been able to get only to the stats.

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
glcm1 = graycomatrix(I);
Stats = graycoprops(glcm1);
```

And it results in the stats.

Stats =

```
   Contrast: 0.5006
Correlation: 0.9269
     Energy: 0.1636
Homogeneity: 0.8925
```

What I want is to show the image of these 4 GLCMs like here.

[image]
It should be simple to output that image, but I'm all new to this thing and don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: `imshow(glcm1, [])`?

Comment: That did return a very small pixel of the Image. Don't know what that is tho. 

 
[Example Images](http://www.fp.ucalgary.ca/mhallbey/examples.htm) Follow the link and find the section "2. Various GLCM texture measures implemented". I want to process the original image to GLCM and show them like that. Contrast,Homogeneity,Entropy etc... Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

GLCM is not Image Matrix , It is shown the pairs of pixels in matrix as shown in the next photo
[image]

Comment: [Example Images](http://www.fp.ucalgary.ca/mhallbey/examples.htm)

I think GLCM can return images. Follow the link and find the section "2. Various GLCM texture measures implemented". I want to process the original image to GLCM and show them like that. Contrast,Homogeneity,Entropy etc... Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can show the gray level co-occurrence matrix of an image through `imagesc`:

```
I = imread('https://raw.github.com/antimatter15/cameraman/master/cameraman.png');
imshow(I)
M = graycomatrix(I, 'GrayLimits', [0, 255], 'NumLevels', 256, 'Offset', [0 1], 'Symmetric', true);
figure
imagesc(M)
colormap(gray)
graycoprops(M)
```

The displayed GLCM corresponds to an offset "one pixel to the right". This matrix is largely diagonal, which means that the pixels' intensities are highly correlated.

[image: glcm]

The features extracted from the GLCM above are as follows:

```
       Contrast: 518.6036
    Correlation: 0.9335
         Energy: 0.0015
    Homogeneity: 0.3772
```